# Alternative to SQLAlchemy ORM reconstructor

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, decoupling

I am currently working on a little application in Python (3.6) able to handle portfolios of stocks, and to do some financial analysis on it.

The functionalities are simply a CRUD interface (Create, Read, Update, Delete) for my portfolios and stocks. They can be persisted in a dabase (using PostgreSQL and SQLAlchemy as ORM)

The thing is, I am aiming at having an **absolute decoupling** between:

- The 'business logic' (located in a package `core`), where I have my Python objects `Stock`, `Portfolio`, `Regression`, etc.
- The 'persistence layer', (located in a separated package `database`), where all the SQLAlchemy metadata and the mapping with the `core` package's objects are defined

I want this separation for several reasons: first I want to be able to launch the `core` package in standalone (with neither any DB installed nor even SQLAlchemy) and, secondly, I think it is a good practice, because in my `core` package, I can really focus on analysis only and not 'polluting' my Python objects with the SQLA `Column`, `relationships`, etc.

I managed to do it so far, using the low-level SQLAlchemy `mapper` and `Table`.
However there is one only point that I cannot figure out. Currently my Python `Stock` object is like:

```
class Stock:

    def __init__(self, ticker: str, exchange: Exchange, name: str=None):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.exchange = exchange
        self.name = name
        self._data = None

    ...
```

The `_data` property is needed to store my financial data, and I want to instantiate it.

But, as you may know, when I load a `Stock` from the database, (in the case where I actually use the `database` pkg), for instance via a command like `session.query(Stock).first()`, then the `__init__` function is not called by SQLA. The only thing I can do is adding a function:

```
@orm.reconstructor
def init_on_load(self):
    self._data = None
```

where `orm` is `sqlalchemy.orm` and is the **only** import of `sqlalchemy` in my `core` pkg. I would like to get rid of it!

Does anyone have an idea? For instance, maybe there is a way to instantiate the `_data` property from inside the `database` package, through the `mapper`, but I don't know any.

Thanks

Comment: If all you need is a default value (`None` in this case), can you not just put `_data = None` at the class level?

Comment: "[`reconstructor()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html#sqlalchemy.orm.reconstructor) is a shortcut into a larger system of “instance level” events, which can be subscribed to using the event API - see [InstanceEvents](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents) for the full API description of these events.", of which [`load`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.load) might interest you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have a look at the Events Management section, and in particular this load event, and will post an answer with my solution, quoting you. Or if you prefer you could repost your comment as an answer, so that I could validate it!

Comment: @univerio but in this case, all my instances will share the same _data, won't they?

Comment: They'll share the same `_data` if you want the default value to be a mutable object, e.g. `_data = {}`, but if you just want it to be a value, e.g. `_data = None`, then they'll share the same value but it won't matter. If you want it to be a mutable object, you can put a descriptor in place that initializes the value on first access.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Response to comment, "Data mapper is not instrusive so you can use One Data Class across your Data layer and Business layer". That is only true if the project is small. but when projects goes bigger, the underlying data store won't change in the same pace as your business logic. Then you need some middle layers e.g adapters, transformers etc.

Anyway, if your problem is not about decoupling, just want to make it works, then use the @orm.reconstructor or any hacks. Otherwise, use least hacks or workaround as possible.

======================================

Based on my experience, ORM classes is coupled with underlying OMR framework, no matter what framework you choose, SQLAlchemy, MongoEngine etc.

If you want to abstract the data storage and can switch data engine in future. Then better write your core business logic on some plain old classes. Then in storage module, provide a function to convert ORM class to your plain class.

E.g

```
# module core.objects
class Stock:
    def __init(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

# business logic
class BusinessLogic:
    @staticmethod
    def logic(stocks: list[Stock]):
        pass
```

Then in storage package

```
from core.objects import Stock as CoreStock
# This is the ORM dependent class
class Stock(Model):
    name = columns.Text()
    price = columns.Float()

    @classmethod
    def to_core_objects(instances):
        return [CoreStock(instance.name, instance.price) for instance in instances]
```

Now you can easily switch storage engines, mysql, csv etc, and much easier to write unit test.

Comment: "ORM classes is coupled with underlying OMR framework" is somewhat true for Active Record based ORMs, but need not be for data mappers (OP has already separated the logic in plain classes and persistence using mapping).

Comment: ORM is orm. That is intrusive, data mapper only works for one ORM framework, and it has its own quirk. Otherwise, the OP don't have such problems. Intention is one thing, implementation is another. @IljaEverilä

Comment: [No hacks required](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.InstanceEvents.load). The `reconstructor()` decorator is just a convenience function around the load instance event, which allows for the desired decoupling.

Comment: I'm btw not trying to say that adapters etc. are entirely unnecessary, especially in large projects. But in this particular case there exists a clean solution that fits the bill.